# IFM with Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, active-directory

Can you use IFM Media from a 2008R2 box to build and promote a Server 2012 DC? Or can you only use IFM media from another 2012 box?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. That is blocked by the code, which checks the `hiddentable` table in ntds.dit for the OS build that the IFM media was sourced from.  Even if you found a workaround, it would in no way be supported by MS. Moral of the story is use IFM sourced from the same version of Windows that you intend to restore to.